# Why is std::nullopt_t part of the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, c++17

I don't understand the reasoning for the inclusion of `std::nullopt_t` in the standard. Does it exist strictly for convenience, or is it required in some niche circumstances?

To be clear, I understand that it is used as an argument to construct empty `std::optional` objects. But considering a default constructor for `std::optional` already exists, there seems to be no obvious motivation for the existence of `std::nullopt_t`. Must such a constructor and assignment operator exist for `std::optional` to conform to a particular concept? If so, which concept?

Comment: It's for [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: Reading the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t) should be sufficient to clear any of your doubts, no?

Comment: Apologies for the vague question. std::nullopt's intended use is clear enough. My question revolves around the actual necessity for the existence of the relevant std::optional constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Looks like it was mainly for convenience and to give it pointer like behavior: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html#rationale.nullopt

Comment: @NathanOliver IMO that should be an answer, albeit with some attention to the situations pointed out in that passage that it claims require the disambiguation. Well: **the** answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`nullopt_t` is the type of `nullopt` which indicates disengaged `optional` state. `nullopt` allows disambiguating overloads such as (example from the `optional` proposal):

> ```
> void run(complex<double> v);
> void run(optional<string> v);
>
> run(nullopt);              // pick the second overload
> run({});                   // ambiguous
> ```

Comment: Considering the optional can be default constructed in-place in that situation, is the ease of disambiguation important? The caller could always provide optional<string>{} as the argument directly. I feel that there are many other situations where explicit default construction (rather than providing an empty initializer list) is required anyway.

Comment: @ZarkBardoo Using `optional<string>{}` forces repeating the type name. Not having to repeat yourself is good. Same reasoning is behind introducing `auto` variable type deduction as well. It's not necessary, but it helps.

Comment: @user2079303 Are you trying to imply the standard is DRY? ;)

Comment: @user2079303 Agreed. Would it then be fair to say that "strictly for convenience" is the answer to my original question? Are there, for instance, situations, where nullopt can be cheaper than default constructing the std::optional object?

Comment: @ZarkBardoo in the sense that for example `auto` is "strictly for convenience". "Convenience" makes writing bugs harder. We could replace the whole standard with [brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), and we could still write all the same programs. It would just be much less "convenient".

Comment: To clarify, I don't disagree that it's for convenience, I just want to point out, that the point of considering whether it is for convenience, is moot.

Comment: @user2079303 I see your point, but I think it might be an oversimplification. For instance, std::variant added convenience, but I might argue that a class like std::monostate _needed_ to exist following the addition of std::variant. std::optional similarly adds convenience, but its implementation doesn't require the existence of std::nullopt nearly to the extent that std::variant requires std::monostate.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another example I just ran into:

```
// GCC: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
// Clang: error: initializer list cannot be used on the right hand side of operator ':'
std::optional<int> x = some_condition ? std::optional(0) : {}; 

// works
std::optional<int> y = some_condition ? std::optional(0) : std::nullopt;
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ reference says it all:

> `std::nullopt_t` is an empty class type used to indicate `optional` type with uninitialized state. In particular, `std::optional` has a constructor with `nullopt_t` as a single argument, which creates an `optional` that does not contain a value.

[std::nullopt_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t)

Comment: t's clear what nullopt it, it's unclear why do we need it